# Grails run-app not starting when adding mx4j dependency

Tags: grails, mx4j

I am working on a Grails project that has a transitive dependency on mx4j jar. I cannot avoid the dependency which is using the mx4j jar, and I have used this jar in the provided scope.

But whenever I run my application using `grails run-app` I get the following error:

`Error loader constraint violation: loader (instance of ) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of ) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
    at javax.management.MBeanServerBuilder.newMBeanServerDelegate(MBeanServerBuilder.java:49)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:302)`

If I remove the `provided 'mx4j:mx4j:3.0.2'` dependency, I get a ClassNotFoundException on an mx4j Class.

I think the internal grails tomcat is loading "javax/management/MBeanServer" class and since it is also loaded via mx4j, it is causing the above issue. Is there anyway I can resolve this issue at the grails end? I cannot avoid the mx4j dependency in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it. I removed the mx4j dependency and also excluded the dependency that was bringing in mx4j dependency from the original dependency I had added. When I removed mx4j I got the same ClassNotFoundException, but I avoided the dependency which was needing it. Some how all started working :)

Answer (score 0):

Other than opening up the jar and removing the offending classes (which is iffy at best), I don't see many options for you with regards to classpath fiddling.

How about using Spring (which you already have onboard in your grails app) to [export your mbeans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-exporting)?

Comment: The issue with opening the jar and removing the classes is that, since the jar is in my local M2 Repo, it may be used by other applications as well. I will try the spring way and update